# How to immediately terminate program after receiving data from ORSSerialPort?

Tags: swift, orsserialport

Yesterday, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780446/cannot-receive-data-from-orsserialport) question about cannot receive data from ORSSerialPort. A solution is to add `RunLoop.main.run()` right after calling `mySerial.SendString(data: "test")`. However, this will make the program run forever. If I want the program to immediately terminate after receiving data, how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple workers in Swift Command Line Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590701/multiple-workers-in-swift-command-line-tool)

Comment: I, for instance, used that solution on linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43111274/1801544 to end my script when the download have finished. I have a `func run(completion: (() -> Void))}` async method which is the main method to call, and on the completion I set the boolean value to `true`.

Comment: could u explain a little more detail?

Comment: Since the linked question is quite forward, What’s your asynchrone code? Do you have a callback? A closure?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43111274/344733 is a good way to do it that is quite close in general to the solution you're already using.